# compare differences between coefficients in different regression equations

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to compare differences between coefficients in different regression equations.

Specifically, I have 2 regressions looking at the effect of Importance to Donate on Guilt, Feeling, and Responsibility

```
aov_I <- aov(newdata_I$AV_importance_to_donate~newdata_I$AV_guilty+newdata_I$AV_percieved_resp+feeling_I)
summary(aov_I)

aov_S <- aov(newdata_S$AV_importance_to_donate~newdata_S$AV_guilty+newdata_S$AV_percieved_resp+feeling_S)
summary(aov_S)
```

I would like to compare the differences between the coefficients in these two different regression equations.

How can I do this??

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: "compare" as in subtract one from the other, or simply putting them in the same table?

Comment: @avid_useR see if one is significantly higher than the other 

e.g. I expect 'feeling' to be higher in the first regression and 'responsibility' and 'guilt' to be higher in the second

Comment: I understand, but what are you trying to do _programmatically_ is my question. What would the expected output look like? A dataframe with the coefficients listed as two separate columns, or a vector of coefficient differences after you subtract the second set from the first?

Comment: If instead you're asking how you _should_ compare the coefficients, it would be better suited here: [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can view just the coefficients by doing aovI$coefficients[2] and aovS$coefficients[2] and then combine them into a dataframe using cbind, then just view with a bar graph if you don't need to do a real statistical comparison

Comment: Thanks very much for your response @MaryLev ! This is for my dissertation so I will need to have a real statistical comparison... would you know how to do this by any chance? thanks again!

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided more code in your answer

Comment: @Maria So it seems like you have 2 datasets with the same independent and dependent variables, but you want to look at the difference in how your independents affect your responses in each?  If that's right, then you could combine your datasets and add group as a variable (so either I or S), then run a multiple linear regression with group as a categorical variable, so:

Comment: @maria  ``` lm(Response~Importance+Guilt+Feeling+Group) ```